# Configuration Management for node express application

Tags: node.js

In our team, we have an internal node application built using Express API. We have a config files written using `dotenv` format and packaged along with our deployment process. That means whenever I change any config value, I had to deploy my entire application code again even if there is no change in code and start the service.

I would like to ease the deployment process. So far, I've the following approaches in my mind:

- Pull-out the config files from the application code package and deploy only config if there is change in config, and restart the application service. This would require the outage, but no build and deployment of the application code.
- Put the configs in the DB like Redis / Mongo, and read from there. If there is a config change, do the change in DB and call `/reload` api which we can build in our application to reload the config object. I'm not sure about the side-effects of this approach.

Kindly please share your experience and how did you overcome.